# Create a new list from a raster list in R

Tags: raster, r, list

I am very new to R, so this is tough for me to explain. But, I have a raster list made up of 3872 elements (or separate rasters, I am guessing) and I am hoping to make a new smaller raster list by pulling out some of the rasters in the larger list based on their name.

The data I am using are raster .bin files for sea ice concentration values from NSIDC. Here are my steps to uploading the .bin files into R and creating the raster list itself:

```
#making the raster
pixel <- 25000 #pixel dimension in meters for both x and y
xMin <- -3837500 #From NSIDC: ulxmap -3837500
xMax <- xMin + (pixel*304)
yMax <- 5837500 #From NSIDC: ulymap 5837500
yMin <- yMax - (pixel*448)
r <- raster(nrow=448, ncol=304, xmn=xMin, xmx=xMax, ymn=yMin, ymx=yMax)
projection(r) <- '+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs'

# making the function to loop over the files
bin_raster <- function(ymd){
filename <- paste("data/","nt_", ymd,"_v1.1_n.bin", sep="")
con <- file(filename, 'rb')
x <- readBin(con, "raw", 300)
x <- readBin(con,"int", size=1, signed=FALSE, 150000)
close(con)
x[x==251] <- 1
x[x>251] <- 0 # set all non-ice pixels to 0% ice cover
x[x<251] <- x[x<251]/250 #scale ice cover to 1
rr <- setValues(r, x) # place result in raster

#changing file names to just the date
geoTiffFile<- paste('geoTiffs/', ymd,'.tif',sep='')
rr <- as.list(rr)
}

# writing the loop 
# making a vector of all dates for every .bin file (extract all file names, then isolate date)
files <- list.files("data") # make a vector of all file names
head(files)
dates <- str_sub(files, 4, -12) # drop all text except for the date

# creating an empty list 
raster_list <- rep(NA, length(dates))

# looping over all the files and filling the list
for(i in seq_along(dates)){
raster_list[i] <-   bin_raster(dates[[i]])}

# renaming the files so that only the date remains
list_names <- str_sub(dates, 0, -5)
names(raster_list) <- list_names
```

So now I have a raster list (raster_list) of all my files that are named by their date. How do I create a new list and choose specific dates to put into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of anything with names in R can be subsetted using square brackets.

Lets make a test list from the first day of 1991 to the last day of 2001.

Make the day strings in the right format:

```
> d = format(seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"),
                 as.Date("2001-12-31"),by="day"),
             "%Y%m%d")
> head(d)
[1] "19910101" "19910102" "19910103" "19910104" "19910105" "19910106"
> tail(d)
[1] "20011226" "20011227" "20011228" "20011229" "20011230" "20011231"
```

Make a list that long with content 1 to N

```
> Ldata = as.list(1:length(d))
```

give each element the day string name:

```
> names(Ldata)=d
```

To get a sub-list, subset using single square brackets:

```
> Ldata["20011223"]
$`20011223`
[1] 4010
```

To get a subset of them, for example March and April, you can use base string matching to see what names have 03 or 04 in the right place.

```
> april = grep("^....04..$",names(Ldata))
> march = grep("^....03..$",names(Ldata))
```

and then extract those elements into a new list:

```
> Lmarchapril = Ldata[c(march, april)]
>
```

Check the names are expected:

```
> names(Lmarchapril)
  [1] "19910301" "19910302" "19910303" "19910304" "19910305" "19910306"
  [7] "19910307" "19910308" "19910309" "19910310" "19910311" "19910312"
 [13] "19910313" "19910314" "19910315" "19910316" "19910317" "19910318"
 [etc]
```

You now have a sublist for March and April. R doesn't care what the elements in the list are, they could be numbers like in my example, or rasters, or file names, or data frames, or fitted models....

Comment: So my raster list expands across 10 years - I have a raster file for almost every day of the year for these 10 years. But, I just want to subset the March and April dates for each year. Is there another way to select them rather than having to type out a list of all their names?

Comment: You need to create a vector of the names you want using basic string matching operations or constructions. If you edit your question to show us the format of a few of the raster list names I'll revise my answer for you. At the moment your code is unrunnable by anyone else because we dont have (and we dont really want) your 3872 files.

Comment: The names are "19910101", "19910102", "19910103"....."20011231" so they are the dates of each sea ice concentration raster. Was thinking someone else might have tried to make a sub-list out of a raster list and could provide some insight.

Comment: It doesn't matter that its a list of rasters - any list of things can be subsetted the same way in R. If you just want March and April then that's names that match the pattern "....03.." and "....04..". Base R string matching and then subset. Will edit....

Comment: It looks like that worked. Thank you!