# Crop raster list to a shapefile

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, clip

I am very new to R, so please bear with my explanation. I have a raster list made up of 671 objects that I am hoping to clip to a shapefile.

At this link I explain how I uploaded the original .bin files and got help making a sub-list of just the March and April dates (I'm working with sea ice concentration rasters from NSIDC): [Create a new list from a raster list in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354525/create-a-new-list-from-a-raster-list-in-r)

Now, I am hoping to crop that new sub-list. Here is what I have done (where "list_mar_apr" is the sub-list and "boundary" is the shapefile):

```
# Import and check shapefile
boundary <- readOGR("file_folder/shapefile.shp")
plot(boundary)

# Crop subset to the shapefile
list_mar_apr_crop <- crop(list_mar_apr, boundary)
```

I keep getting an error message that reads:

> unable to find an inherited method for function 'crop' for signature
> 'list'.

Comment: Do you want to crop *each raster* in the list to the shapefile? Does `crop(list_mar_apr[[1]], boundary)` do the right thing for the first raster? In that case you need to loop over the rasters in the list with `lapply`. If all the rasters are the same size and extent then alternatively you could make a multi-band `stack` or `brick` instead of using a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_mar_apr_crop <- lapply(X = list_mar_apr, FUN = crop, y = boundary)
```

This will apply the `crop()` function to each raster element of your list, using the boundary object for the cropping.

Comment: After trying that, I got this error message: "unable to find an inherited method for function 'crop' for signature 'integer'". I am thinking that it is because the files in the list are originally .bin files, so they appear as just a list of values. Do I need to project them somehow first?

Comment: Can you post the result of `str(list_mar_apr)`? Is it occupied by a series of file names, raster objects, or something else entirely?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post a photo, but it says (where ... is a new line): "list of 671... $ 19910301: int 60... $ 19910302: int 61... $ 19910303: int 62"

Comment: We ended up getting it working! Turns out the last step we did (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354525/create-a-new-list-from-a-raster-list-in-r) was wrong, which was throwing this whole step off. Thanks for your help!